# Why does http post always return null data?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, http-post

I am making an **Ionic** application where I am trying to make an `http post` request. When I test the request with **Postman** it works fine, but when I try to do it with **Ionic** it returns null data and status code 0. I have tried the two snippets below, inside a `factory`, with no result:

**First:**

```
return {
        signUp: function ($name, $surname, $email, $password, $tel) {
          $http.post($connectionString + 'users/signup',
            {
              'name': $name,
              'surname': $surname,
              'email': $email,
              'password': $password,
              'tel_num': $tel,
              'is_company': false
            })
            .then(function ($returnedData) {
              return $returnedData;
            }, function ($returnedData) {
              return $returnedData;
            });
        }
      };
```

**Second:**

```
return {
          signUp: function ($name, $surname, $email, $password, $tel) {
            $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: $connectionString + 'users/signup',
              data:
                "name=" + $name +
                "&surname=" + $surname +
                "&email=" + $email +
                "&password=" + $password +
                "&tel_num=" + $tel +
                "&is_company=" + false,
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
              .then(function ($returnedData) {
                return $returnedData;
              }, function ($returnedData) {
                return $returnedData;
              });
          }
        };
```

**Note** that I have passed `$http` as a parameter to my `factory`.

Comment: Have you looked at the browser error console and network log to see how far the request is proceeding?

Comment: @Alex K. Yes, it says error 400 Bad Request.

Comment: @Alex K. It also says Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/test/users/signup. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

Comment: You need to configure the script your running on the server to allow CORS requests

Comment: @Alex K. thank you very much! I would never have found this!

Comment: Also just a note if you're using Google Chrome, you might get CORS errors. Try using a different browser (I use Firefox when I do CORS) or a device/simulator. Make sure to allow rules in the Cordova `config.xml` file.